# Mongodb - aggregate match subarray

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I trying to match the data in Subarray for some reason it is grouped like this.

***Data :***

```
{
"_id": 1,
"addresDetails": [
    [
        {
            "Name":"John",
            "Place":"Berlin",
            "Pincode":"10001"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Sarah",
            "Place":"Newyork",
            "Pincode":"10002"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Name":"Mark",
            "Place":"Tokyo",
            "Pincode":"10003"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Michael",
            "Place":"Newyork",
            "Pincode":"10002"
        }
    ]
]
}
```

***I tried with this Match query:***

```
{
  "$match":{
    "attributes":{
       "$elemMatch":{
            "$in":["Mark"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting No data found , How do i match the elements in this subarrays.

Comment: Is it a correct assumption that you are looking for any document that contains "Name":"Mark" (in the 2nd level of the embedded arrays)? Can you also share what you are expecting as the result?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- aggregation way, in general if you are stuck and query operators or update operators seems not enough, aggregation provides so much more operators, and its alternative.
- 2 nested filter in the 2 level arrays to find a `Name` in array `[Mark]`

*maybe there is a shorter more declarative way with `$elemMatch`, and possible a way to use index, also think about schema change, maybe you dont really need array with array members (the bellow doesnt use index)

*i used `addressDetails` remove the one s else you will get empty results

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=625d89668b39bcf74dae273c)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$ne": 
       [{"$filter": 
           {"input": "$addressDetails",
            "as": "a",
            "cond": 
             {"$ne": 
               [{"$filter": 
                   {"input": "$$a",
                    "as": "d",
                    "cond": {"$in": ["$$d.Name", ["Mark"]]}}},
                []]}}},
        []]}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apparently nest `elemMatch` as well, e.g.:

```
db.collection.find({
  "addresDetails": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        "Name": "Mark"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This matches your document, as shown by [this mongo playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DKUFlLimhrd), but is probably not very efficient.

Alternatively you can use aggregations. For example `unwind` may help to flatten out your nested arrays, and allow for easier `match` afterwards.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$addresDetails"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "addresDetails.Name": "Mark"
    }
  }
])
```

You can find the mongo playground link for this [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Uh6nHbOvTG). But unwind is usually not preferred as the first stage of the aggregation pipeline either, again because of performance reasons.

Also please note that the results for these 2 options are different!